# Optimize BaseControllerWithDataContext to avoid magic string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datacontext, magic-string

How would I go about avoiding the use of the so called magic strings in the following code?
Specifically the: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"]`

Basically this class implements a DataContext inside the Controller. This class is a part of a Class Library, and won't have direct access to the DataContext class (ie .dbml file)

```
public abstract class BaseControllerWithDataContext<TDataContext> : BaseController where TDataContext : DataContext, new()
{
    public static TDataContext CurrentContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"] == null)
            {
                TDataContext context = new TDataContext();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"] = context;
            }
            return (TDataContext) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"];
        }
    }

    protected TDataContext DataContext
    {
        get { return CurrentContext; }
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filteContext)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"] == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var context = (TDataContext) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["DomainDataContext"];

        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried to do it with another generic type parameter, but was having problems with the `"cannot use sealed class 'System.String' as type parameter constraint"`

So what would be the best way to go about this ?

Comment: I would be asking why you are storing the DataContext in there in the first place.

Comment: Don't do that. inject it as a dependency.

Comment: @AdamCarr Ease of Access

Comment: @Nkosi Why shouldn't I do it like that ? I still have the BaseController for controllers which doesn't need db access. And through this process I avoid having to instantiate it. Through BaseControllerWithDataContext, it is only instantiated once the action is called and disposed once the action has completed.

Comment: The DataContext is disposable and you would be best creating per request.   Holding it memory should be sufficient. Injecting it makes testing the controller easier but the controller will still be dependant on the DataContext.